# Stucked up with Indirect Multiplication Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, recursion, iteration

While I was getting ready for an exam I found a question that asks for an algorithm for indirect multiplication.

Question :

> Two integers *p* and *q* can be indirectly multiplied by the following method.
>
> If the product expected is r (initially 0) then, if q is odd p is added to r and q is reduced by 1, If q is even p is doubled and q is halved(i.e. q becomes q/2)
>   If *q* is even *p* is doubled and added to *r* and *q* is halved(i.e. *q* becomes *q*/2)

It is further stated that indirect multiplication is used in digital computers in which the direct multiplication is expensive

And by trying for hours I managed to find an iterative and a recursive algorithm, but they aren't perfect.

Iterative

```
int multiply(int p, int q){
    int r=0;
    while(q!=0){
        if(q%2==1){
            r += p;
            q--;
        }
        else{
            r += 2*p;
            q = q/2;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

Recursive

```
int multiplyRec(int p, int q){
    if(q==1)
        return p;
    if(q%2==1){
        return (p + multiplyRec(p, q-1));
    }
    else{
        return (2*p + multiplyRec(p, q/2));
    }
}
```

For example, when I multiply 6 by 5 the answer in both algorithms is 36 while it has to be 30. But if I change it in a way to get 30 then multiplying by 1 fail.

I was surfing the internet but couldn't find a match.
Can somebody please explain what is wrong with the above algorithms or if there is an error or if there is a better way to do them.

Comment: The "p is doubled" part is supposed to be taken as a modification to the *stored* value of `p` (with the result subsequently added to `r`).  You are instead adding twice `p` to `r` without updating `p`.

Comment: Near dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13666591/179910

Comment: You tell us what is not perfect with your algorithms, then we can help find the reason. I.e. please describe what is wrong, what happens unexpectedly, what does not happen though desired, crash, hang, wrong result, in which cases?

Comment: `qp = (q-1)p + p` makes sense, but second condition `(q/2)(2p) + 2p = 2p+qp != pq` can someone explain this for me?

Comment: @Yunnosch edited with the issue'

Comment: @JohnBollinger pointed out one mistake: _"p is doubled"_ means you should **modify `p`**, not just use `2*p` in your expression

Comment: For the recursive algorithm, I'd prefer stop condition  `if(q==0) return 0;` If anybody tried to multiply 7*0, you'd be caught in endless recursion otherwise...

Comment: Have you tried multiplying 7*-1? Negative input is valid with int, if you cannot cover it correctly, you're in trouble as well. Easy fix for iterative version: `if (q < 0) { q = -q; p = -p; }`. You don't want to have that check in every recursion, so you might have a separate non-recursive entry function calling the recursive one afterwards. The other variant: exclude negative input by using *unsigned* int...

Comment: Swapping p and q if abs(p) < abs(q) should - at least for larger values - result in some performance benefit.

Comment: Side note: Considering the fix of algorithm in given answers, you can merge if and else into one single branch: `while(q) { r += q%2 * p; p*=2; q/=2; }`: r will be added 0, if q is even, p otherwise; fine so far; after subtracting 1 in case q is odd, next time q *is* even. And for both `q == 2*n` and `q == 2*n+1` the result of `q/2` is `n`...

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm in your quote box is wrong.  It should be:

> If the product expected is r (initially 0) then, if q is odd p is added to r and q is reduced by 1, If q is even p is doubled and q is halved(i.e. q becomes q/2)

That is, when q is even, you JUST double p, you DO NOT add it to r.

It's also missing the implicit termination condition of q == 0

This corresponds to simple binary long-mulitplication -- for each 1 bit in q you add p left shifted by the position of the 1 bit; for each 0 bit in q you do nothing.

This is usually written as

```
while (q != 0) {
    if (q & 1)  // q is odd
        r += p;
    p *= 2;
    q /= 2;
}
```

That's because when q is odd, subtracting 1 will make it even, so you can immediately do the next step of doubling p and halving q.  Since integer division rounds down, dividing the odd number by 2 also does the -1 implicitly.

Comment: Would you like to highlight and maybe even explain the difference?

Comment: Some part for explanation: Why don't I have to add on multiplying by 2? Imagine I only divide by two all the time? Answer: At some point, even powers of two will reach value 1, and thus one final add *will* occur under any circumstances...

Comment: No it is not. And the fact that you think so is supporting my proposal to make the difference more obvious.

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta Fact is - the algorithm as described in the question simply is *wrong* - no matter if you cited from question sheet as is or introduced the error yourself... But if you discover really having cited 1:1, then you should contact professor/examiner/... and hint him/her to the error.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm will work fine if you follow the rule below instead of the one you stated:

> If the product expected is r (initially 0) then, if q is odd p is added to r , If q is even p is doubled and q is halved(i.e. q becomes q/2)

Sample code:

```
int mult(int p,int q){

int r=0;

if(q%2==1)
{
    if(q!=1)
    {
        r+=p;
        //q--;
        return r*q;
    }

    r+=p;
    return r*q;
}

else if(q%2==0)
{
    if(q!=0)
    {
        p=p*2;
        r+=p;
        q=q/2;

        return r*q;
    }

    return 0;

}}
```

Comment: @BinaraMedawatta you're welcome, but technically the question is wrong. If you decrease the value of q by 1 , it will never give you the correct result. Hope I could help you.

Comment: The algorithm given will never terminate once you get q is odd.  Your sample code just uses `*` (builtin multiply) to avoid that case, but can't really mulitply as a result.